# Loop over entity reference view for email using Business Rules

Tags: views, 8

I have an entity reference built to show user name, email and last access.  This works fine and shows data in the view.  I am attaching this to a [Business Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module action so that I can loop over members of a role to email them all.

I have the first action which does the loop and second displaying a message to validate.  The problem is the email field will note render correctly.  Here is syntax

```
{{action_name->name}} - {{action_name->mail}}
```

These variables should be available.   The "name" will render correctly but email does not.